# I've trying to include PyEnchant library to my exe-file using cx_Freeze (windows)

Tags: python, pyqt, cx-freeze, pyenchant

I've trying to include PyEnchant library to my exe-file. How do I do this?

I have been testing this with cx_Freeze:

"C:\Python33\python.exe" "C:\Python33\Scripts\cxfreeze" "C:\Temp\CSV Viewver\csv_viewer.py" --base-name=Win32GUI -–include-modules "pyenchant" --target-dir "C:\Temp\CSV Viewver\dist"

This does not work :/

---

I am using: Python 3.3 (x86) / cx_Freeze 4.3.1 (x86) / pyenchant 1.6.5 (x86)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The package that you import is called `enchant`, not `pyenchant`.
2. <s>There isn't an `include-modules` option to cxfreeze - it's called `packages` (or `modules` for single file modules).</s> [I was wrong about this] [See the docs](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html#build-exe).

So try it with the option `--packages=enchant`.

But if your script imports enchant, cx_Freeze should automatically pick that up, so that you don't need to specify it.

Comment: "--packages=enchant" gives:
cxfreeze: error: no such option: --packages

But using the link you provided, I dwelled a little deeper into the docs. I was able to compile my exe, but still it was missing some depencies... I'll have to look at that more on my spare time. But thank you for your info!

Comment: My mistake, it appears the docs and the script don't match up, and it *is* `include-modules`.

Comment: --include-modules=enchant seems to work, although like you said, Thomas K, it was picked up by cx_Freeze. But when I try to run my compiled exe-file, I still get an error:

---------------------------
cx_Freeze: Python error in main script
---------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console3.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "C:\Scripts\Spellcheck\spellcheck.py", line 14, in <module>
    from spellcheck import spellcheck...


I pasted the whole error here: http://pastebin.com/DNdaesqE

Comment: That looks like a bug in pyenchant, that will only show up when it's frozen with Python 3.

Comment: That's what I thought. I should have looked at this more carefully. I submitted this error into github to the developer of pyenchant. Thank you for your help, Thomas =)

https://github.com/rfk/pyenchant/issues/25